# How to configure pf.conf file for mitmproxy on macOS?

Tags: macos, proxy, port-forwarding

I'm trying to configure mitmproxy tool ([guide](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/transparent/osx.html)). I'm stuck on Step 3, where I need to modify pf.conf file. My question is essentially about the last sentence:

> Place the following two lines in a file called, say, pf.conf:

```
rdr on en2 inet proto tcp to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr on en2 inet proto tcp to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
```

> These rules tell pf to redirect all traffic destined for port 80 or 443 to the local mitmproxy instance running on port 8080. You should **replace en2 with the interface on which your test device will appear**.

I deal with `pfctl` for the first time and I can't get what is *interface* about and what should I paste instead of `en2`.

I've looked through [OpenBSD guide on Port Forwarding](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/rdr.html) but it has nothing about the `rdr` command. Please, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open Terminal and type:

```
ifconfig
```

You will see 'en0', 'en1', 'en2'... and on and on. You're looking for whichever ethernet port is active (likely en1), and is going to be listed first.

If you type:

```
info ifconfig
```

at the command line, you'll find

```
"interface - this parameter is a string of the form "name unit", for example, "en0".
```

Hope this helps.